# Reduce Datastore Read Operation

Tags: google-app-engine

Under new pricing scheme of Google App Engine, I get a surprise pricing table as shown below.

[image]

The culprit is, I get a huge increased in "Datastore Read Operations", just within a few hours, although there are only less than 50 calls to my [DownloadServlet](http://jstock.hg.sourceforge.net/hgweb/jstock/jstock-cloud/raw-file/a80d0c143a16/src/org/shuwnyuan/cloud/DownloadServlet.java)

DownloadServlet will just read blob (Usually less than 1 MB) from database, and return it to user. Is there anything I can do to optimize my code, so that I will not hit the free quota limit so fast.

Comment: You should switch to use the blobstore instead of of storing the data in the datastore as a blob.

Comment: It's more or less impossible to help without seeing your code. Why not just budget some increased quota, though?

Comment: @NickJohnson The code is published. Please look at linked directed by "DownloadServlet".

Comment: @ShayErlichmen I realize blobstore is rather a new feature, as when I develop it, app engine doesn't come with this feature. But, will it help to reduce quota? Thanks for the info anyway.

Comment: @NickJohnson The problem is, from end user point of view, I cannot accept the fact, why my bill increased suddenly in several tenth fold. I just feel like I am being cheated. I choose Google App Engine initially as it seems CHEAP. Now, if I know this is the ACTUAL cost of running in Google server, I will not choose to to do at the very first day. Now, I am being locked!

Comment: How did your bill increase tenfold given your app is not billing enabled? Have you used appstats to determine where your inefficiencies are?

Comment: Regarding billing, you might be interested to know that the cost for datastore read ops (as of November 2011) is only $0.70 / Million Ops. If you really want to host your database in some external place, you could use URLFetch in your app to fetch this external database and reduce your datastore cost.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're doing a lot of reads because you've broken your files up into 1MB chunks in the datastore. As a result, you have to do one read per chunk, and because you're not using key names or IDs, you're also doing a query for each, further depleting your quota.

Store your data in the blobstore instead.

Answer (score 3):

If the data that you read from the datastore is relatively static (e.g. text for a blog entry), you could consider caching the data in the [memcache](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/memcache/overview.html).

There are no guarantee on how long the data could remain in the memcache, so you need to regularly re-fetch the data from the datastore in case the data in the memcache is invalidated, but the savings to the datastore read ops would be quite considerable.

Comment: It will not help much. As the data is specifically for individual user. I would say with <50 users, you will see your billing starts to run.